# Pre-fetching / caching videos for later playing

Tags: javascript, video, video-streaming, html5-video, mediaelement.js

How can I force the browser to begin downloading a video stream (or video file) without triggering it to play immediately? Please note, I will want to play this video to the user - but not immediately, so the goal is to pre-fetch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the `preload` attribute in the `<video>` element to indicate that the browser should start downloading the file as soon as the page loads; for example:

```
<video src="..." preload></video>
```

Comment: If I have multiple video tags with preload, will they load concurrently or sequentially? Will they preload streams as well?

Comment: That's up the the browser, but I suspect you'll be limited by existing per-domain/server connection limits.